# Perl find whether more than one string is in a log file then print

Tags: perl

Hi just learning Perl so please forgive.  What I am trying to do is if the log file contains one or more of these strings Failed, Error or Skipped then print out an error.(the log could have one or more of all of the strings in the arrary or just one instance)  I have tried variations on the below code.  It compiles but it only prints out Done.

```
#!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl

my @matches = (
  qr/"Failed"/,
  qr/"Skipped"/,
  qr/"Error"/,
 );

$mylog = "email_log.txt";

open (LOG, "<$mylog") || die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

LOG_READER:
while (my $loglines = <$LOG>) {
  if ($loglines =~ /@matches/) { 
   print "Error in the log\n";
   last LOG_READER;
  }
}
close($LOG);

print "\n Test is Done \n";
```

I have also tried

```
while ( $_ = <INPUT> ) {

  if( $_ =~ @matches ){
    print "\n Build Failed! \n";
  }
}
```

thank you for any assistance
Modified code that works
This solution uses an array
    #!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl

```
my @matches = qr/Failed | Skipped | Error/x;

my $mylog = "email_log.txt";

open (LOG, "<$mylog") || die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

LOG_READER:
while (my $loglines = <LOG>) {
  if ($loglines =~ /$matches/) { 
   print "Error in the log\n";
   last LOG_READER;
  }
}
close(LOG);

print "\n Test is Done \n";
```

This solution is what I used
    #!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

```
my $myfailures = qr/Failed | Skipped | Error/x;
my $mylog = "email_log.txt";

open (LOG, "<$mylog") || die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

LOG_READER:
while (my $loglines = <LOG>) {
  if ($loglines =~ /$myfailures/) {
   print "Error in the log\n";
   last LOG_READER;
#    last;
  }
}

close(LOG);

print "\n Test is Done \n";
```

Another solution
    #!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

```
my $mylog = "email_log.txt";

open (INPUT, "<$mylog") || die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

LOG_READER:
while(<INPUT>) {
    next unless /(Failed|Skipped|Error)/;
    print "\n Build failed \n";
    last;
}

close(INPUT);

print "\n Test is Done \n";
```

Solution #4

```
#!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $matches = "Failed|Skipped|Error";
my $mylog = "email_log.txt"; 

open my $LOG, "<", $mylog|| die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

while (my $loglines = <$LOG>) {
    if ($loglines =~ /$matches/) { 
        print "\n Error in the log\n";
        last;
    }
}
close($LOG);

print "\n Test is Done \n";
```

Thank you everyone for the contributions.  They all worked really wish I could give everyone the correct answer.  With the provided solutions I was able to get all the variations working.

Comment: I used the tripleee answer in my solution but have modified the code above with mpapec input to fix this script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if ($loglines =~ /@matches/) {`

This is your problem. You cannot use an array as the regex to match against. Try this instead:

```
  if ($loglines =~ /"(Failed|Skipped|Error)"/) {
```

> `while (my $loglines = <$LOG>) {`
>    ...
>   `close($LOG);`

Oh and this should be just `LOG` without the dollar signs.

With `use strict; use warnings;` you would get some better diagnostics. Get into the habit.

Comment: #!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl
use warnings;


$mylog = "email_log.txt";

open (LOG, "<$mylog") || die 'Could not OPEN $mylog file';

LOG_READER:
while (my $loglines = <LOG>) {

  if ($loglines =~ /(Failed|Skipped|Error)/) {
   print "Error in the log\n";
   last LOG_READER;
#    last;
  }
}

close(LOG);

Answer (score 2):

You are making this far too complicated.  You really just need to do some reading on how regexps work, but its quite a simple problem to solve:

```
while(<INPUT>) {
    next unless /"(Failed|Skipped|Error)"/;
    print "\n Build failed \n";
    last;
}
```

Comment: Or indeed even just `perl -ne 'warn "$_" and last if /Failed|Skipped|Error/' email_log.txt` on the command line (reverse the quotes on Windoze).

Comment: If you want a one-liner, don't use perl at all, just use grep.

Comment: Yeah, `egrep -m 1 "Failed|Skipped|Error" email_log.txt`

Comment: this works but if there is more than one error in the log file I get Build Failed many times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use array of regex but for this particular case it's not needed,

```
my $matches = qr/"Failed" | "Skipped" | "Error"/x;
```

and then

```
if ($loglines =~ /$matches/) { .. }
```

Comment: This worked as well.  I am on Windows so I had to remove the quotes.  Really, really helpful thank you.

Comment: The quotes are from your code; if they are not needed, that's another reason your attempt didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. I would always use `use warnings; use strict;`.

I would also modify your `open` calls to use the 3-arg, lexical scoped version.

```
open my $fh, "<", $mylog;
```

What exactly are you trying to match here?

```
my @matches = (
  qr/"Failed"/,
  qr/"Skipped"/,
  qr/"Error"/,
 );
```

An example from your log file would help. You're trying to match these keywords wrapped in actual quotes. Is this what you intended?

email_log.txt example:

```
Your build "Failed"
"Skipping" foo.c
```

This will match with or without surrounding quotes:

```
my $matches = "Failed|Skipped|Error";
my $mylog = "email_log.txt";
open my $fh, "<", $mylog; 

while (my $loglines = <$fh>) {
    if ($loglines =~ /$matches/) { 
        print "Error in the log\n";
        last;
    }
}
close($fh);
```